# How can I order nested includes records with Rails 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

As the title states: how can I order nested `includes` records with Rails 4?

Here is an overview of the models:

**Product**

- title
- price
- etc

**ProductSize**

- product_id
- size_id

**Size**

- width
- height
- order

A `Product` has many `Sizes` through `ProductSize`.  `Sizes` are to be ordered through `order` on the `Size` model. I have a `default_scope` of `order('order DESC')` set on the `Sizes` model

I want to be able to get a list of `products`, and then loop through each `product` and show a list of available `sizes`, ordered by the `size` `order`.  I want this all without making inefficient queries (n+1 problem), so I am using `includes`.

To do this, I run `Product.includes(:product_sizes => [:size]).all` which generates:

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products"

SELECT "product_sizes".* FROM "product_sizes" 
WHERE "product_sizes"."product_id" IN (X, X, X, X)

SELECT "sizes".* FROM "sizes" 
WHERE "sizes"."id" IN (X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X) ORDER BY `order` ASC
```

As you can see my my ordering will be off since it will use the order in which I got the records from the `product_sizes` query.  You can also notice that the query for `sizes` does indeed have the `ORDER BY` statement, but it does not affect the end result.

My initial thought would be that the `size` should just be `joined` onto the `product_size` query.  Unfortunately I have no idea on how to do this using `includes`.

Ideally the generated queries would look more like:

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products"

SELECT "product_sizes".* FROM "product_sizes" 
WHERE "product_sizes"."product_id" IN (X, X, X, X)
JOIN "size" ON product_sizes.size_id = sizes.id
ORDER BY `size`.`order`

SELECT "sizes".* FROM "sizes" 
WHERE "sizes"."id" IN (X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X) ORDER BY `order` ASC
```

Comment: Joining `sizes` you substantially increase amount of transferred data as `product_sizes` columns will be duplicated for each size of the same product. `Product.preload(:product_sizes).first.sizes`?

Comment: Not sure if it works but wild guess: `Product.preload(:product_sizes).eager_load(:product_sizes => :size)`, wouldn't recommend it though even if it does.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and mapped the `sizes` association directly onto `products`. Here is what I have:

product.rb model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_sizes
  has_many :sizes, through: :product_sizes, source: :size
end
```

product_size.rb model:

```
class ProductSize < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :size
end
```

size.rb model:

```
class Size < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope -> { order(order: :desc)}
end
```

seeds.rb file: (you can run rake db:seed to see how it works)

```
# Size.delete_all
# Product.delete_all
# ProductSize.delete_all

size1 = Size.create!(width: 20, height: 5, order: 3)
size2 = Size.create!(width: 30, height: 15, order: 2)
size3 = Size.create!(width: 10, height: 123, order: 1)
size4 = Size.create!(width: 14, height: 12, order: 4)
size5 = Size.create!(width: 24, height: 32, order: 5)
size6 = Size.create!(width: 45, height: 13, order: 7)
size7 = Size.create!(width: 54, height: 31, order: 6)
size8 = Size.create!(width: 35, height: 14, order: 8)
size9 = Size.create!(width: 42, height: 41, order: 9)
size10 = Size.create!(width: 13, height: 54, order: 10)

product1 = Product.create!(title: "Chair", price: 21.00)
product2 = Product.create!(title: "Table", price: 120.00)
product3 = Product.create!(title: "Microwave", price: 34.00)

ProductSize.create!(size: size1, product: product1)
ProductSize.create!(size: size3, product: product1)
ProductSize.create!(size: size5, product: product1)

ProductSize.create!(size: size1, product: product2)
ProductSize.create!(size: size3, product: product2)
ProductSize.create!(size: size4, product: product2)

ProductSize.create!(size: size1, product: product3)
ProductSize.create!(size: size2, product: product3)
ProductSize.create!(size: size3, product: product3)
ProductSize.create!(size: size8, product: product3)
ProductSize.create!(size: size9, product: product3)
ProductSize.create!(size: size10, product: product3)
ProductSize.create!(size: size4, product: product3)
ProductSize.create!(size: size5, product: product3)
ProductSize.create!(size: size6, product: product3)
ProductSize.create!(size: size7, product: product3)

products = Product.includes(:sizes).references(:sizes).order('"sizes"."order" DESC').to_a
products.each do |product|
  puts product.title
  product.sizes.each { |size| print "#{size.order} " }
  puts    
end
```